# Using array values in mysql Where

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple MYSQL SELECT querys feed in each other, the first one selects the row id, puts them in an array,  The second SELECT query needs to use those values 10,14 etc, to acess the rest of the restaurants info in other tables, the problem im having is the second query is only selecting the last phone_number based on the last value in the array 14.

```
$city= 'london';
$cuisine ='indian';


$sql=(" SELECT restaurant_id FROM restaurants WHERE  city = '$city' AND cuisine=                     '$cuisine'  ");

mysql_select_db('RESTAURANTS');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); 
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))


foreach ($row as $key => $value) { 
$i++; // increment $i by one each loop pass 

echo "Cart Item $i ______ key = $key | value = $value<br />"; }





$sql1 = "SELECT phone_number FROM restaurants WHERE  ($key) IN ($value)";



mysql_select_db('RESTAURANTS');
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn ); 
if(! $retval1 )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC))


foreach ($row1 as $k => $v) { 
$ii++; // increment $i by one each loop pass 
         print_r ($v);


}
?>
```

outputs

```
Cart Item 1 ______ key = restaurant_id | value = 10
Cart Item 2 ______ key = restaurant_id | value = 14

// the phone_number
444444444
```

Only selects the phone_number of 14 not 10 also why? do I need some sort of extra function to loop through the array again, iv'e tried implode and mysql_value functions, iv'e tried everything I can think off, any help appreciated.

Comment: Learn how to do SQL joins, and your database will kiss you in gratitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is attrociously formatted. Had you used proper indenting, you'd see that your first while() loop is malformed:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                                                      ^--- no {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) { 
    $i++; // increment $i by one each loop pass 

    echo "Cart Item $i ______ key = $key | value = $value<br />"; }
```

As such, it will retrieve all the rows of that first query and output the individual fields. But since you didn't use proper bracketing, the next chunk of code (your next sql query/loop) is **NOT** part of this first while loop, so you only execute that phone number fetching query **ONCE**.

It should be

```
 while(... first query) {
      print values
      do inner query
      while (fetch inner query) {
           print values
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that you are looping through the restaurant ID's and running a query for eacy restaruant, putting only that value into `$retval1` - thus when you query using that array, it only has the last telephone number in it.